# Where to get the metasploit decloaking source code?

Tags: security, metasploit

I have recently been reading about getting a web site visitors internal ip address and came across decloak.net which is the ip resolver used by the metasploit framework.

Unfortunately the sample page is down and the link to the download is broken - does someone know where to get the source? Is it contained in metasploit any longer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the [wayback engine](http://wayback.archive.org/):

```
http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://www.metasploit.com/releases/framework-3.3-dev.exe
http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://www.metasploit.com/releases/framework-3.3-dev.tar.bz2
```